# extjs xtype button style variable

Tags: javascript, variables, extjs, extjs4, width

I want to put the variable(btnWidth/bthHeight) to width(height) of button:

```
Ext.define(
  'TestPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    width: 300,
    height: 35,
    btnHeight: 25,
    btnWidth: 25,
    items: [{
      xtype: 'button',
      width: btnWidth,
      height: btnHeight,
    }, {
      xtype: 'button',
      width: btnWidth,
      height: btnHeight,
    }  
  }
```

This is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'btnWidth' of undefined
```

**Question**

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use `initComponent`  method for [`panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel). In `panel` you will define you custom config and you can get inside of `initComponent` method.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bbr)**, I have created a demo using `panel`, `button` and `initComponent` method. I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.define('TestPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 300,
    btnHeight: 38,
    btnWidth: 50,
    title: 'Buttons example',
    initComponent: function (config) {
        var me = this,
            btnWidth = me.btnWidth,
            btnHeight = me.btnHeight;

        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button 1',
            width: btnWidth,
            height: btnHeight,
            margin: 10
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Button 1',
            width: btnWidth,
            height: btnHeight
        }];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

//Create component
Ext.create('TestPanel');
```